# How to retrieve data from jdbc step in soapui?

Tags: soapui

I have a soapui project where a jdbc step connect to db and select some data from a table.

for example : select * from person;
result =

```
<Results>
   <ResultSet fetchSize="0">
      <Row rowNumber="1">
         <PERSON.CREATED_AT>2016-02-26 18:39:41</PERSON.CREATED_AT>
         <PERSON.FIRST_NAME>PIERRE-RICHARD</PERSON.FIRST_NAME>
 </Row>
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the "PIERRE-RICHARD" and store it into a variable.

I know how to save a data into a variable from a response but here I cannot.

Is there a groovy way to do it or inside the jdbc step?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can you not? The response if formatted as XML. Just transfer `${name_of_JDBC_step#ResponseAsXml#//Row[1]/PERSON.FIRST_NAME}`.

Comment: Using index(like Row[1]) in the xpath is not always works if the element order changes.

Comment: @Rao Sure it works, if you include `order by ...` in your SQL. ;)

Comment: Hmm, not talking about this particular case. In general, xml may contains list of elements and that need not be jdbc step like you pointed here and there is no luxury to do so.

Comment: @Rao I have no idea what you said, but it appears to be completely unrelated to this post.